# C#: Regex to do NOT match to a group of words

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, regex-negation

I need a regex to match a word that is not in a group of words. I have googled and Stacked question an found some suggestions. But they all were about matching a group of chars, not words. so I tried to write a regex by myself. But I couldn't find a correct regex. Here is my last one that I have tried until now:

```
(?:(?!office|blog).)+
```

my words are `office`, and `article`. I want input words that are not in this group. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that your Regex should look like this:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\b(?!office|blog|article)\w+\b");
MatchCollection words = r.Matches("The office is closed, please visit our blog");

foreach(Match word in words)
{
   string legalWord = word.Groups[0].Value;
   ...
}
```

This will return "The", "is", "closed", "please", "visit" and "our".

Comment: Depending on what the OP is parsing this can turn into a big ball of string. For instance, it should not turn "officer" to "r", so it can be adjusted to look at whole words, but what about "offices"? :)

Comment: If the number of ignored words are huge or dynamic in anyway the approach would be different - I would read all words using a Regex like \b\w+\b and filter the words using a HashSet<string>.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question clearly.Because you try for a regex pattern of **office|blog** but in next line you say your word is **office** and **article**.Ok,i try here with those 3 words(**office,blog,article**).Use that as your needs,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("Now the office is closed,so i spend time with blog and article writing");
while (m.find())
{
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("office|blog|article"); //change it as your need
    Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(m.group());

    if(m1.find())
    {
        System.out.print(m.group().replace(m.group(),""));
    }
    else
        System.out.print(m.group());
}
```

**Output:**

> Now the  is closed,so i spend time with  and  writing

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve this problem myself. Found my answer here: http://www.regextester.com/15

The regex: ^((?!badword).)*$

What it means:

- ^$: match the entire search string only (beginning (^) and end ($)).
- ()*: match 0 or more of what's contained.
- (?!badword): look ahead of the current character, and make sure that "badword" as a whole does not match.
- .: match any single character.

The important part is that this is matching only one character at a time, and, after matching each character, checking to make sure that "badword" does not **immediately** follow.